# Javascript display various time zones

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset

The following script should be displaying the current local time based on the offset of -10 (Hawaii), but it's not working.

Can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
<h3>Current Time in Arizona is 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

    if (minutes < 10)
    minutes = "0" + minutes

    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
    }

    document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>")
//-->
</script>
</h3>
```

Comment: Is this all the code? `calcTime()` doesn't seem to exist anywhere...

Comment: where are defined `hours` or `d`?

Comment: You need to include the code for `calcTime` and the definitions of `hours` and `d`.

Comment: Clearly, I didn't need the downvote. I need help! Obviously, I'm missing something here. I think `document.Write(CalcTime('Hawaii', '-10'));` should be `document.Write(currentTime('Hawaii', '-10'));`

Comment: So, I've updated the script above. What I'm trying to do is account for a timezone variation and I can't seem to get it right. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ymRb/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the code you've shown just returns the current local time.  It doesn't even *attempt* to change it for a specific time zone.

Secondly, you need to read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  In particular, read the section titled "Time Zone != Offset".

Now it just so happens that Arizona and Hawaii don't currently use daylight saving time, so you *could* adjust by offset if those were your only two concerns.  But I'm sure you are looking for a more general solution.

To do it properly, you will need a library that implements the IANA time zone database.  [I list several of them here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).  For example, here is an example of displaying the current time in Los Angeles using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) plugin:

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("h:mm a")
```

If you're just looking for a quick and easy way to put a clock on your web site for a particular time zone, then I recommend using [the free solution offered by timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/clocks/free.html).

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to move a *Date* by some offset in *minutes*/your choice

```
function offsetDate(offsetMinutes, d) {
    if (d) d = new Date(d);
    else d = new Date();
    if (offsetMinutes) d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() + offsetMinutes);
    return d;
}
offsetDate(-10*60); // Thu Sep 05 2013 12:03:06 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Now use *UTC* functions to get the time

Comment: Do you mean like this? `Date.UTC(year, month, day[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[,ms]]]])` The time is the only thing that will display. But, it needs to be able to display the time based on the clicked state. So, clicking on Texas will show one time, and California will show another time. Not sure how to "use UTC functions"...

Comment: @webfrogs `.getUTCMinutes()`, `.getUTCHours()`, etc

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is, rather than trying to move timezone, adjust the _Date_ so the UTC values are what you'd expect the local time to be in that timezone, then read out the _UTC_ time.