# how to get current time of a given timezone using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I get current time of a given timezone using jQuery ?

I have a dropdown where user select the timezone (i.e. PST or EST etc.) and I need to display current time based on the selected timezone

Comment: Do you have the UTC Offset of each timezeone? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset

Comment: Googling `how to get current time of a given timezone using jQuery` brings up plenty of options, for example [get current time in a specific country via jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18392482)

Comment: Try this plugin: http://momentjs.com/timezone/ check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18648135/2611927

Comment: possible duplicate of [get current time in a specific country via jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392482/get-current-time-in-a-specific-country-via-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for that. To get a local timestamp, just use the [getter methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Getter) that don't have `getUTC` at the start of their name.

For example, to get a timestamp in the form of YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss, you'd do this:

```
var d = new Date();
var date = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()],
    time = [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()];
alert("It's now: "+date.join('-')+' '+time.join(':'));
```